# SQL COUNT function to find commonality

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

The question I'm facing is as follows: list the first letters of the product names and their totals. Only display the letter and count if there are 3 or more products beginning with that letter of the alphabet.

Clearly the query requires the use of the COUNT aggregate, but I am spinning my wheels looking at this.  How do I write this query?

expected output:

```
ProductName           Total  
C                      9  
G                      11
```

ETC...

I'm assuming I need a SUBSTRING in my select statement

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ProductName,1,1)    AS ProductName,
       COUNT(ProductName)            AS Total
FROM   Products
```

But using WHERE with a count function will give me an aggregate error is SQLServer2012?

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output. Also tag the Database you are using

Comment: sure: see above for edits.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `aggregate` function's in `where` clause to filter the result

To filter the group's you have to use `having` clause instead of `where` clause. Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ProductName,1,1)    AS ProductName,
       COUNT(ProductName)            AS Total
FROM   Products
group by SUBSTRING(ProductName,1,1)
having COUNT(ProductName) >=3
```

Comment: PERFECT! I was missing the SUBSTRING in my GROUP BY clause. Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You just need a proper group and having clause:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(ProductName, 1) AS ProductName,
    COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM Products
GROUP BY
    LEFT(ProductName, 1)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```